# how to calculate grand total of a sub-total column in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

I am trying to get summary report in C#. I have used SQLite database for storing my data.
In the given image, I have calculated total price for each location. Please help me find out grand total of the TotalPrice column in the last row as shown in the image. Thank you.
[Please check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY0fg.png)

this is my query.

```
  SELECT Job_Mst.JobCode
    ,Location_Mst.LocationName
    ,sum(JobTransaction.TransactionPrice) AS TotalPrice
FROM Job_Mst
LEFT JOIN JobTransaction ON Job_Mst.JobId = JobTransaction.JobId
LEFT JOIN Location_Mst ON Location_Mst.LocationId = Job_Mst.LocationId
WHERE JobTransaction.DATE BETWEEN @firstDate
        AND @secondDate
GROUP BY Job_Mst.LocationId

I am fetching data from 3 tables..
```

Comment: What have you tried till now to achieve this?

Comment: Please show us some code. How do you access the data in the image?

Comment: Run SQL query and use the SUM function.

SQL: `SELECT SUM(TotalPrice) FROM TableName`

Comment: Hi, please check. I have added my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this once

```
WITH Totals
AS (
    SELECT Job_Mst.JobCode
        ,Location_Mst.LocationName
        ,sum(JobTransaction.TransactionPrice) AS TotalPrice
    FROM Job_Mst
    LEFT JOIN JobTransaction ON Job_Mst.JobId = JobTransaction.JobId
    LEFT JOIN Location_Mst ON Location_Mst.LocationId = Job_Mst.LocationId
    WHERE JobTransaction.DATE BETWEEN @firstDate
            AND @secondDate
    GROUP BY Job_Mst.LocationId
    )
SELECT *
FROM Totals

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total'
    ,''
    ,SUM(TotalPrice)
FROM Totals
```

Comment: You can accept this as answer if this works for you